# Detect whether FocusEvent of component is lost or gained

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

I implementing a EventQueue and get notified when AWTEvents are send.
I wait till instances of FocusEvent are send to the dispatchEvent methode.

The FocusEvent by itself does not have a methode to ask if the focus of the component is gained or lost.
The methode paramString returns a String in which the information is placed, but i dont want to hack or pars the String. A contains call can give me the answer, but the returnes String is no constant, so it could change in the future.

The paramString methode of FocusEvent is like:

```
 switch(id) {
      case FOCUS_GAINED:
          typeStr = "FOCUS_GAINED";
          break;
      case FOCUS_LOST:
          typeStr = "FOCUS_LOST";
          break;
      default:
          typeStr = "unknown type";
    }
    return typeStr + (temporary ? ",temporary" : ",permanent") +
        ",opposite=" + getOppositeComponent();
```

Do you know another solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with "evt.getID()"?  It returns `FOCUS_LOST` or `FOCUS_GAINED`?

Comment: when you want to implement something during the last minutes in the office you sometimes get crazy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Markus - I know that feeling well.  Glad to help.